# LibGDX with GWT ignore source file changes

Tags: libgdx

I'm using LibGDX with GWT to create a web version of an app that runs without problems on the desktop, Android and iOS. However, the HTML version of the app had a few problems with constructs unsupported by GWT. I've fixed these issues and I get a proper HTML/GWT app that I can start within my browser.

However, I found some additional problems and I've fixed the first one but the changes are ignored by the GWT compiler: I still get the same error. This is when using Eclipse but also when doing stuff via the Windows command prompt.

I've tried the following:

- Cleared the browser cache (Chrome, Firefox won't run but that's a different problem)
- Removed all Gradle cache files from my home directory
- Removed all generated files (gradlew.bat clean)
- Re-imported the project in Eclipse
- Rebuild the Gradle model in Eclipse
- Use the "Dev Mode On" bookmarklet to force development mode
- Use the "Dev Mode Off" bookmarklet to force release mode

In all cases the web app still fails to run properly and I get the same error in the JavaScript console.

Any suggestions on how to proceed here?